# Table-Per-Type and multiple association using same Foreign Key in Entity Framework CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, polymorphic-associations, table-per-type

I have the following CodeFirst Classes. I am trying to model a TPT structure here. An user can login and access his Individual profile or his many company profiles. `Individual` and `Company` have polymorphic association with other tables.

```
public class LoginDetail
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      //Other Properties

      public virtual Individual Individual { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies{ get; set; }
}

public abstract class Profile
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      //Other Properties
      public virtual int LoginId { get; set; }
      public virtual LoginDetail Login{ get; set; }
}

[Table("Individuals")]
public class Individual : Profile
{
      //Other Properties
}

[Table("Companies")]
public class Company: Profile
{
      //Other Properties
}
```

This maps to `LoginDetails`, `Profiles`, `Individuals` and `Companies` Table. Everything works fine but in order to associate one-to-many  relation between `LoginDeatils` and `Companies` it creates an extra `LoginDetail_Id` in `Companies` Table. This breaks other parts of my model. How do i tell entity framework to use `LoginId` in `Profiles` Table for both the one-to-one relation between `LoginDeatils` and `Individuals` and one-to-may relation between `LoginDeatils` and `Companies`

Answer (score 0):

you should use InverseProperty and ForeignKey attribute ,

try this code :

```
public class LoginDetail
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  //Other Properties

  public virtual Individual Individual { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Login")]
  public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles{ get; set; }
}


public abstract class Profile
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  //Other Properties
  public virtual int LoginId { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Profiles")]
  [ForeignKey("LoginId")]
  public virtual LoginDetail Login{ get; set; }
 }
```